# Name for pattern that allows only certain classes to construct another class

Tags: java, design-patterns, naming

I have to write a test for the login dialog that shows up on my website, but there are two, and *only two* access points for this login dialog. Ideally, my page objects should reflect the restricted access to this login dialog.

1. When you `clickLogin` on the `Header`, a `LoginDialog` pops up
2. When you `postComment` on an `Article`, and you aren't logged in (and we'll assume you aren't for simplicity), a `LoginDialog` pops up.

Here's what it looks like in code:

```
new LoginDialog().login();          // shouldn't be allowed
new Header().clickLogin().login();  // should be allowed
new Article().postComment().login() // should be allowed
```

I came up with a method for getting around this. `LoginDialog` only has two constructors, which both take in an object that can only be constructed in either `Header` or `Article`.

```
public class LoginDialogTest extends WebTest {
  @Test
  public void testLoginDialogFromHeader {
    new HomePage().loadPage();
    new Header().clickLogin().login();
    verifyLoggedIn();
  }

  @Test 
  public void testLoginDialogFromArticleComment {
    new ArticlePage(42).loadPage();  // Load an article with id=42
    new Article().postComment().login();
    verifyLoggedIn();
  }
}   

public class LoginDialog {
    public LoginDialog(Article.CommentButton commentButton) {
    }

    public LoginDialog(Header.LoginButton loginButton) {
    }

    public void login() {
    }
}

public class Article {
    public class CommentButton {
        private CommentButton() {
        }

        public LoginDialog click() {
            return new LoginDialog(this);
        }
    }

    public LoginDialog postComment() {
        return new CommentButton().click();
    }
}

public class Header {
    public class LoginButton {
        public LoginDialog click() {
            return new LoginDialog(this);
        }
    }


    public LoginDialog clickLogin() {
        return new LoginButton().click();
    }
}
```

My question is whether or not this is an existing pattern, and if it is, what is its name? If it isn't, what would be a good name for it?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you mean by "not letting" other classes construct a `LoginDialog`.  If it's your app, you can simply not put a constructor in other classes, so I'm wondering if your concern is (1) a new developer coming into the project and inadvertently constructing an object it shoudn't, or (2) a plug-in class that your program loads dynamically that a third party could write, or (3) something else?

Comment: @ajb The API I'm building is for Selenium WebDriver-based tests, so someone creating a `LoginDialog` when it doesn't actually exist in the browser is a real concern because they could use methods that will look for web elements that don't currently exist on the page. So, say you have some class `WebTest`, and you have some test method, `testLoginDialog`.  My main concern is (2), a new developer coming in and misusing my API by creating a new `LoginDialog` without accessing it from an `Article` or a `Header`, which would crash the test because no login dialog would be present on the webpage.

Comment: I think any class could create a new `LoginDialog` by saying `new LoginDialog(new Header().new _())`.  That might be hard to do inadvertently, so maybe it's sufficient.  It would not be good enough to protect against malice.

Comment: @ajb _() is a private constructor, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: Ahh, I missed that!  In that case, what you have seems like a good solution, but there's no reason to call it `_`.  A normal descriptive name would be better.

Comment: @ajb Yeah it's definitely not descriptive at all lol. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this would be a foolproof way of making sure only `Header` or `Article` could create a `LoginDialog`:

```
public class LoginDialog {
    private LoginDialog() {
        ... code to construct 
    }

    public interface Constructor {
        LoginDialog newLoginDialog();
    }

    private static class ConstructorImpl implements Constructor {
        public LoginDialog newLoginDialog() {
            return new LoginDialog();
        }
    }

    private static ConstructorImpl constructor;

    static {
        constructor = new ConstructorImpl();
        Header.provideLoginDialogConstructor(constructor);
        Article.provideLoginDialogConstructor(constructor);
    }
}
```

and in `Header` and `Article`, provide a public `provideLoginDialogConstructor` method:

```
private static LoginDialog.Constructor constructor;
public static void provideLoginDialogConstructor(LoginDialog.Constructor constructor) {
    Header.constructor = constructor; // or Article.constructor
}
```

and when those classes need to construct a `LoginDialog`:

```
if (!loggedIn()) {
  return constructor.newLoginDialog();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

Since the `LoginDialog` class decides what classes get to have its private object to construct a `LoginDialog`, there should be no way for another class to obtain the ability to construct one using normal means [there might be tricky ways using reflection].

**Note:** I haven't tested this.

Comment: Two concerns with the above answer: 1) "this" needs to be removed 2). There has to be some way to load LoginDialog before Header and Article can create LoginDialog object; otherwise, you get NullPointerException

Comment: @dragon66 First one has been fixed.  (Could also be fixed by giving the parameter a different name.)  Since I haven't tried running this, I'm not sure how to fix #2, but would adding a `static { }` to `Header` that makes a dummy reference to `LoginDialog.class` do the trick?  Or is there a better way?  I'm not completely familiar with the class loading rules--I don't use static blocks very often.

Comment: @ajb: for #2, maybe we can just check if constructor is null or not like this if (!loggedIn()) { if(constructor == null) Class.forName("packagename.LoginDialog");
  return constructor.newLoginDialog();
}

Comment: I edited the question because I am satisfied with the approach I'm using, but I want a name for this pattern so that I can communicate it with my coworkers.

Comment: @michaelsnowden I'm not sure it's a pattern that is known by a name. It's like a factory in that the details about instantiating a class are hidden. But the private constructor is similar to the singleton idiom, although this is quite different from a singleton. It's an application of information hiding and access control, which are lower level design principles (not really patterns).